# test by date in django and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

i need to do a test before setting values in my list so ,

i get a selected value from a combobox and i want to do a test between this value and a variable in my data base .

the source code is : 
first in my template :

```
                 <select class="form-control" id="date_select" onchange="displayAll();">
               <option value="">----- </option>
               {% for v in v_date  %}
               <option id="" value="{{ v.date}}">{{ v.date}}</option>
               {% endfor %}
             </select>
```

so i am gonna do a test with the selected value from the combobox in javascript

this is the source code in js

```
               var date_test = document.getElementById('date_select').value ;

               var locations = [
                 {% for v in vs %}

                    {% if v.date == date_test %}
                      ['okok',{{ v.latitude }},{{ v.longitude}}],
                    {% endif %}

                 {% endfor%}
                   ]
```

the problem is that my source code doesn't work in IF conditions , i don't know if this line is correct  `{% if v.date == date_test %}
                          ['okok',{{ v.latitude }},{{ v.longitude}}],
                        {% endif %}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't make if condition with django variable and javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636205/cant-make-if-condition-with-django-variable-and-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You try to make a comparaison with `=` operator which does not exits.

You have to use [`==`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#operator) operator.

Example from Django documentation :

```
{% if somevar == "x" %}
  This appears if variable somevar equals the string "x"
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is copy/paste from Django documentation so, it works. Could you please upload trace-back ?

Comment: yes but in my example there is a problem , for example ; i tester by {% if v.date == "25-06-2017"  %} and it works but when made the variable by javascript it didn't work

Comment: Is your file a Django template ? Is it load BY Django and not only load as static file ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to another that I've answered to.

Here is [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44636423/7813242).