# can't make if condition with django variable and javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

i variable type table in javascript , and i need to make a test with `if` condition between this variable and a variable from django database but it' doesn't work.

the example :

```
var test_date = "2017-06-23";
var locations = [
    {% for v in vs %}

        {% if v.date ==  test_date %}

            ['okok',{{ v.latitude }},{{ v.longitude}}],

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor%}
        ]
```

the first example doesn't work and i don't know why.

other example :

```
var test_date = "2017-06-23";
var locations = [
    {% for v in vs %}

        {% if v.date ==  "2017-06-23" %}

            ['okok',{{ v.latitude }},{{ v.longitude}}],

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor%}
        ]
```

when i put the value of the variable in the test it's working

Comment: Well, no, you can't do that. Why would you think this would work?

Comment: because i did a test with a value , so i can set this value in variable the do a test with this variable

Comment: Yes but JS can't possibly pass a value to a Django template variable.

Comment: so what i have to do ?

Comment: I don't know about the if statement part but we can render django template tags in javascript by '{{your_django_variable|escapejs }}'

Answer (score 5):

Django part of the template( `{% %}`) is executed on the server, when javascript part is executed on the client side (just in the browser). All the variables inside template tags are django's variables. The point is that django sees text and template tags. It won't execute any line of jacascript.

let me show how django and how javascript sees your first example.

django:

```
some text
    {% for v in vs %}

        {% if v.date ==  test_date %}

            another text

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor%}
        more text
```

Now you see that there isn't any `test_date` variable. If there is no `test_date` variable (it's empty), then it coudn't be equal to `v.date`.

javascript:

```
var test_date = "2017-06-23";
var locations = [
        ]
```

As you see (you can check it in *dev tools* of browser) your server didn't produce any text for javascript, so the `locations` array is empty.

If you simply want to test if `v.date` is equal to some string than you can create variable test_date in *view* corresponding to this template and add it to the context.